# Custom element is not ignored when child is inline-block

Tags: html, css

I've got custom elements in my code which display some odd behaviour when a child element has a `display: inline-block` style.

Consider the following two `div` elements:

```html
<div style="padding: 4px;">
  <randomcustomelement style="background-color: yellow">
    <div style="display: block; height: 36px; background-color: red; width: 125px;">
      <div style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 12px; background-color: green;"></div>
    </div>
  </randomcustomelement>
</div>
<div style="padding: 4px;">
  <randomcustomelement style="background-color: yellow">
    <div style="display: inline-block; height: 36px; background-color: red; width: 125px;">
      <div style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 12px; background-color: green;"></div>
    </div>
  </randomcustomelement>
</div>
```

In the first main `div` it is clear that the custom element `randomcustomelement` is ignored by the browser. It does have a proper width and height, but is not rendered, like expected. In the second main `div`, however, `randomcustomelement` does get rendered, and what more, it has a very strange height of `17px`. I've included an image depicting this through Chrome's element inspector below:

[image: Element inspector results]

The only difference between both examples is that the child `div` which is wrapped by `randomcustomelement` has `display: block` in the first example, and `display: inline-block` in the second example. I've given the `randomcustomelement` a distinct yellow color to also visibly depict that it does get rendered.

This problem is present in all browsers, even though they should ignore the custom element:

> User agents must treat elements and attributes that they do not understand as semantically neutral; leaving them in the DOM (for DOM processors), and styling them according to CSS (for CSS processors), but not inferring any meaning from them.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#extensibility-0

This is really giving me a headache, because I need the inner `div` to be a `display: inline-block`. So I would need the second example's code to give the first example's results.

Comment: The spec that you quote implies that browsers *should not* ignore the element: "leaving them in the DOM" and "styling them according to CSS" are things a browser wouldn't be doing if it ignored the element. So the element is being rendered as an inline box (the initial value of display is inline), an inline box cannot normally contain a block box but it *can* contain an inline-block, and the yellow bit is the descender area under the baseline that the inline-block is sitting on, in accordance with https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#leading

Comment: Your results imply that you don't want the inline-block to have a baseline. If that's the case, *don't use display: inline-block*. It's like giving an element a background color, then complaining that it has a background color.

Comment: Ignore is not the proper word for the browser behaviour indeed. Also, I was not aware that custom elements would still be rendered as an inline box, because in my opinion this contradicts the _but not inferring any meaning from them_ clause in the spec. However, it apparently does, so this gave me some pointers to work with. You are right on using a block in an inline, so I've explicitly stated that the element should behave as an inline-block. Still confuses me why the browser would do this, though.

Comment: The word "meaning" refers to semantics. For example, an article represents a self-contained unit of content, while a div/span doesn't have any inherent meaning. Unknown elements are treated like spans in this regard - the reason they are inline is simply because the initial value of display is inline according to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the style of the randomcustom element to be **display: inline-block** and **height: 0** gives the desired result.

```html
<div style="padding: 4px;">
  <randomcustomelement style="background-color: yellow">
    <div style="display: block; height: 36px; background-color: red; width: 125px;">
      <div style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 12px; background-color: green;"></div>
    </div>
  </randomcustomelement>
</div>
<div style="padding: 4px;">
  <randomcustomelement style="background-color: yellow;height:0;display:inline-block">
    <div style="display: inline-block; height: 36px; background-color: red; width: 125px;">
      <div style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 12px; background-color: green;"></div>
    </div>
  </randomcustomelement>
</div>
```